# How to get the attachment files of an expanded lookup column

Tags: lookup-column, attachments

I am trying to get the attachments from a lookup column. A loose example:

ListA has a column LookupColumnName and I am trying to do something like this:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListA')/Items?
$select=LookupColumnName/AttachmentFiles&$expand=LookupColumnName/AttachmentFiles
```

But I keep getting an error about my query being invlaid. Is what I am trying possible? Or will it just require two separate api calls to the two lists?

#### UPDATE 9/16/2017: From what I have seen it is not possible to do a double expand through a lookup column like I described above, the best way to accomplish this is through two separate calls.